# std::ifstream issue when running outside of IDE

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, iostream

I have a function that works fine when running inside of the Visual Studio debugging environment (with both the Debug and Release configurations), but when running the app *outside* of the IDE, just as an end-user would do, the program crashes.  This happens with both the Debug and Release builds.

I'm aware of the differences that can exist between the Debug and Release configurations (optimizations, debug symbols, etc) and at least somewhat aware of the differences between running an app inside Visual Studio versus outside of it (debug heap, working directory, etc).  I've looked at several of these things and none seem to address the issue.  This is actually my first time posting to SO; normally I can find the solution from existing posts so I'm truly stumped!

I am able to attach a debugger and oddly enough I get two different error messages, based on whether I'm running the app on Windows 7 versus Windows 8.1.  For Windows 7, the error is simply an access violation and it breaks right on the return statement.  For Windows 8.1, it is a heap corruption error and it breaks on the construction of std::ifstream.  In both cases, all of the local variables are populated correctly so I know it is not a matter of the function not being able to find the file or read its contents into the buffer **data**.

Also interestingly, the issue happens only about 20% of the time on Windows 8.1 and 100% of the time on Windows 7, though this may have something to do with the vastly different hardware these OS's are running on.

I'm not sure it makes any difference but the project type is a Win32 Desktop App and it initializes DirectX 11.  You'll notice that the file type is interpreted as binary, which is correct as this function is primarily loading compiled shaders.

Here is the static member function **LoadFile**:

```
HRESULT MyClass::LoadFile(_In_ const CHAR* filename, _Out_ BYTE** data, _Out_ SIZE_T* length)
{
    CHAR pwd[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, pwd);
    std::string fullFilePath = std::string(pwd) + "\\" + filename;

    std::ifstream file(fullFilePath, std::ifstream::binary);

    if (file)
    {
        file.seekg(0, file.end);
        *length = (SIZE_T)file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);

        *data = new BYTE[*length];

        file.read(reinterpret_cast<CHAR*>(*data), *length);

        if (file) return S_OK;
    }

    return E_FAIL;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly, if I allocate std::ifstream **file** on the heap and do not delete it, the issue goes away.  There must be something about the destruction of ifstream that is causing an issue in my case.

Comment: Drop the ancient function signature. You may use `std::vector<unit8_t> LoadFile(const char* filename)` instead, to get rid of new/delete and nullptr output parameters issues (btw: I guess an _Out_ is invalid)

Comment: Thanks @DieterLücking.  The only reason why that hasn't been done already is because, despite the name of the function, it is really only used to load compiled shaders into a struct that has members of the types of the two _Out_ parameters, so it just makes it a bit more convenient at the moment.  Still, the function is universal in nature and it should probably be changed as you suggested or renamed to LoadShader.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I gave up on trying to use ifstream.  Apparently I'm not the only one that has this issue...just search "ifstream destructor crash".

Since this app is based on DirectX and will only be run on Windows, I went the Windows API route and everything works perfectly.

Working code, in case anyone cares:

```
HRESULT MyClass::LoadFile(_In_ const CHAR* filename, _Out_ BYTE** data, _Out_ SIZE_T* length)
{
    CHAR pwd[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, pwd);
    string fullFilePath = string(pwd) + "\\" + filename;

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA fileData;
    HANDLE file = FindFirstFileA(fullFilePath.c_str(), &fileData);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return E_FAIL;

    file = CreateFileA(fullFilePath.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return E_FAIL;

    *length = (SIZE_T)fileData.nFileSizeLow;
    *data = new BYTE[*length];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    if (ReadFile(file, *data, *length, &bytesRead, NULL) == FALSE || bytesRead != *length)
    {
        delete[] *data;
        *length = 0;
        CloseHandle(file);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    CloseHandle(file);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't check the return value of GetCurrentDirectoryA - maybe your current directory name is too long or something?
- If you are already using Win32 (not portable!), use GetFileSize to get file size rather than doing seek
- Better yet, use boost to write portable code
- Switch on all warnings in compiler options
- Enable ios exceptions

Comment: I should check the return of GetCurrentDirectoryA (and I will make that change), but still that doesn't explain why the function works when running inside of the VS debugging environment and not when running externally to it.  I will also take your advice in using GetFileSize() as this is a Windows only app.  As for Boost, I'm actually writing a DirectX based framework (library) and currently the only dependency is the DirectXTK...and I want to keep it that way.  :)

Comment: BTW, implemented ios exception handling and no exception was thrown.  It still fails as described originally.  Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Comment: Fair enough.  Assuming switching to GetFileSize didn't help, try adding logging all over the place, in particular check the values of current directory, file name etc.

Also, what about the source of the arguments, like filename?  Maybe there is something fishy there?

Comment: GetFileSize didn't help; it produced the same values as seek'ing.  Originally I did sprinkle MessageBox() calls everywhere in an attempt to gain insight when running outside of the debugging environment and nothing is out of place.  Even when attaching the debugger once it crashes I see nothing wrong.  As I mentioned before, on Windows 7 the break point is on the return statement of the function and I get an access violation.  It's as though when the local stack objects are being destructed on function return something goes wrong, but as you can see they are all std library classes.

Comment: There must be something else going on with my code because that same function, when exported into a separate test project with nothing else going on, works perfectly-- even outside of the IDE.  I was able to load the same file that my main project attempts to load and there was no issue.  So there must be something wrong with the code that calls this function rather than the function itself, right?  This function is called by another static member function of a class.  I'm investigating...